# Updating Checkbox value in Preference Screen upon changing the value in SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog

I have an app which uses the user's location. I have a dialog(pic below) asking user's permission to "Allow" or "Disallow" the app to use the user's location ( dialog pops up the first time users opens the app after installation OR when user tries to use the location based service while using user location is "Disallow"-ed by the user).
[image: dialog]

I also use preference item(a checkbox)(pic below) in `PreferenceActivity`  where the user can the toggle his preference.
 [image: prefs item]

To change the value of the sharedpreference I have use this code

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
        sharedPrefs =getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("locationPermission", true);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

I had expected the checkbox value to change automatically depending on the dialog selection as the key "locationPermission" holds the value to the checkbox. But it is not so.

Now how do I map the dialog(pic 1) selection to the checkbox value(pic 2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was solved by using 
    `sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`
instead of

`sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `addPreferencesFromResource` in the `onCreate` of your `PreferenceActivity` so that your UI is populated from the preferences.
Also, you may want to make sure that your `CheckBoxPreference` has `android:persistent-"true"` in its XML definition.

Comment: I have called `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs)` in the `onCreate` method of my `PreferenceActivity`. I added the `android:persistent="true"` now. Not helping. The selection in the dialog is not getting reflected in the "Preference Screen"